Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context issue
[Route("Admin/Image/AddImage")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddImage([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromForm] Image image)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        var filename = uploadImages(file);
        image.url = filename;
    }

    if (image.Id == Guid.Empty)
    {
        imgRepo.CreateAsync(image);
    }
    else
    {
        imgRepo.updateImage(image);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

Repository
public async Task updateImage(Image image)
{
     try
     {
         if (image == null)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(image));
         }

         var existingImage = await _dbContext.images.FindAsync(image.Id);

         if (existingImage != null)
         {
              // Update the properties of the existing image
              _dbContext.images.Entry(existingImage).CurrentValues.SetValues(image);

             // Save changes to the database
             await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
         }
         else
         {
             throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Image with ID {image.Id} not found.");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // Log the exception or handle it accordingly
         Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
     }
}

This error is thrown in repository exception while updating:

A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance.


You forgot to await your call to the repository:
await imgRepo.updateImage(image);

You put the recommended "Async" suffix on the Create method name so it looks like a bit of a slip up forgetting it on the Update method.
public async Task updateImageAsync(Image image)


EF context is always registered as scoped service, which is just "live as long as HTTP request lasts". And HTTP request is done processing when you return from your method processing the request:
[Route("Admin/Image/AddImage")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddImage([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromForm] Image image)

So if it ends, context is disposed of. And what you are doing here:
var filename = uploadImages(file);

or here
imgRepo.CreateAsync(image);

is starting methods that use context, but you do not await them (so they just start to run, not completing the work using the context).
So the method goes on, finishing processing of HTTP request, causing the db context to be disposed of, while you started working using it.
So, you get an exception, when you do not await the work using context and letting context be disposed of. To prevent that, you need to use await - then the method won't finish before you get the work done :)
var filename = await uploadImages(file);

and here
await imgRepo.CreateAsync(image);

